# git bash cannot find module npm-cli.js

Tags: node.js, git, bash, npm

```
$ npm install
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I have noticed this

> C:\c\Program Files\

I think that the path is being overrided, I have set the paths in my environment variables

NodeJs works good when I do`node -V` I get the version and when I do `npm -V` it crashes how can I solve this

PS: I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: What's your PATH set to? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with either git or bash, can you check if npm crashes with the same error if you run it from the command prompt that comes with Windows?

Comment: Yes I have tested it in power shell and it works just fine, but I need to fix and git bash too for some reasons

Answer (score 4):

In `Program Files\nodejs\npm`, `node.exe` is executed and *not a node script*, because of this, `git-bash` converts `npm-cli.js`'s path to a Windows path.

> ```
> npm Version: 3.10.10
> Platform: MINGW64_NT-6.1 2.5.0(0.295/5/3) 2016-03-31 18:47 x86_64 Msys
> ```
>
> When I run npm (/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm) in a git bash (which uses
>   MINGW) the npm script throws: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
>
> The problem is that the npm shell script executes a window node.exe
>   but supplies it with a unix path for the npm-cli.js.
>
> As I see it the fix is to also convert the path with cygpath for MINGW
>   as well in /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm line 6-8:
>
> ```
> case `uname` in
>     *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
>     *MINGW*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
> esac
> ```

Read [NPM issue #18499 on GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18499) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, it's due to this variable located in environment variables:

> MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

I don't know why this conflict is happening, in any case If i find it I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

you should install the only LTS version of node
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: It's the LTS version that has this problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you have reinstall the Node.Js and previously you have set the node path in environment variable then you should remove it then it will work